# Want to hide Android toast when app in background

Tags: android, toast

If I issue a toast when my App's activity is not in the foreground then the toast will still show up on the screen. How can I prevent my toast from showing up when my app is running in the background. i.e with none of its activities currently the activity being shown.

I am thinking that I must somehow detect that my activities are not the activity currently being shown and when true not issue any toasts; but how would I detect this condition?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set a flag when your app is in the background (i.e. in `onPause`), and don't send out toasts if the flag is set.

If you have tons of activities, you can define your own `Activity` base class that wraps this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting a variable or some indicator when the `onPause()` method is called for that activity to denote its been put into the background, then turn that indicator off when `onResume()` is called?

Then let that toast occur if the indicator is off.

Answer (score 0):

In my app, queued toasts appearing again and again when app goes into background so I did following to solve the problem.

Add code to detect when app goes into background. One way to register life cycle handler. For More detail [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414171/how-to-detect-when-an-android-app-goes-to-the-background-and-come-back-to-the-fo)

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MyLifecycleHandler());
```

`App.inBackground = true;` when app goes to background and show toast using SmartToast class

```
public class SmartToast {

    static ArrayList<WeakReference<Toast>> toasts = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void showToast(@NonNull Context context,@NonNull String message){
        //this will not allowed to show toast when app in background
        if(App.inBackground) return;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toasts.add(new WeakReference<>(toast));
        toast.show();

        //clean up WeakReference objects itself
        ArrayList<WeakReference<Toast>> nullToasts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (WeakReference<Toast> weakToast : toasts) {
            if(weakToast.get() == null) nullToasts.add(weakToast);
        }
        toasts.remove(nullToasts);
    }

    public static void cancelAll(){
        for (WeakReference<Toast> weakToast : toasts) {
            if(weakToast.get() != null) weakToast.get().cancel();
        }
        toasts.clear();
    }

}
```

call `SmartToast.cancelAll();` method when app goes into background to hide current and all pending toasts. Code is fun. Enjoy!