# Is it possible to resume always to default activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

I'd like to resume any activity in my application to default one.

Is it possible or not?

Comment: Have a [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8034536/593709)

Comment: @AdilSoomro unfortunately, it's since API level 14, I need to support level 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean resume it after home is pressed ?
If yes than

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this,DefaultActivity.class));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes . possible . 
keep delault activity alone into history stack .

this you can achieve by setting `noHistory=true` (in `AndroidManifest`) for all the activities except the default one . alternatively you can set same thing by java code using appropriate flag along with intent of startActivity .
Now on back press , app will navigate to default screen always .

in case this default screen is not the first one approach might be :

you can create a method which will navigate user to that screen and call it in `onBackPress()` of all activities .

Answer (score 1):

Solution can be:
1. You can overwrite onresume method of activity and can start desire activity with clear stack trace after finishing the current activity.