# Android KitKat: Implement a background service to do something when an application is unloaded (or loses foreground)

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to implement a service (or similar) on Android KitKat (4.4.2) in order to detect which is the foreground app and make something depending on which app it is "foregrounded".

I have read a lot of threads about determining which is the app is the foregound ON THAT MOMENT (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14044662/1683141). But I'm not able to see any thread about keeping this service continuosly monitoring in order to detect any changes on foreground. Kind of loop? Event registering?

For example, I want to be notified when LINE (messaging app) has or loses foreground. So I suppose the service has to be registered to some kind of event (I think Broadcast here is useless) in order to be notified and then take some action.

I don't know if that is possible. I hope it is.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unable to keep your service alive if system decide to kill it. You are also unable to keep your service alive if your app is "unloaded" (whatever you mean), because your service is part of your app (and APK) and will be unloaded too.