# Quantifying Battery Drain in Android

Tags: java, android, performance, battery, programmatically-created

Currently, I am trying to quantify amount of battery (in percentage or mAh) drain by my App in background vs foreground mode. From:

[How can we calculate/ to know, how much battery life my user defined application utilising?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343774/how-can-we-calculate-to-know-how-much-battery-life-my-user-defined-application)

It looks like, we need to manually monitor the percentages in the Settings page to quantify. Is there a way/ open source android project to programmatically calculate the drain w.r.t to my app?

Any pointers would help!