# How to detect application is coming from background?

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I know that is application coming from background? I have a scenario like in when the application is coming from background I need to check one property and then based on that I need to launch a layout with a webview. If I use onPause() and onResume() for this, it's being called whenever it's moved from one activity to other activity. But I want this to be called when the app comes from background. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9876683/1218762

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the above solution is working for almost all devices except HTC. It's giving the current application's package as the previous application task.