# Is it possible to find out when Android app returns from background?

Tags: android-lifecycle, android

So, the idea is: user launching application, and I have to perform task X.

User work some time and then quit (app is in background now).

Then he open app again (from background) and I have to perform task X again.

In first case, I can simply use `onCreate()` of custom `Application` class, but it is not that simple with the second one - there's no `onResume()` method or something. Any ideas?

Comment: Use onCreate, onResume, onPause etc. of your Activity derivative classes instead

Comment: @NobuGames but `onResume` and `onPause` also executing when we move to/from another activity, and it's not my case.

Comment: Maybe the following question is of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414171/how-to-detect-when-an-android-app-goes-to-the-background-and-come-back-to-the-fo

Answer (score 0):

Accroding to [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png) every time activity is no more shown to user the same method is called, no matter if it went background by pressing "Home", or was overlayed by another activity.