# Show the splashscreen when return from background android app

Tags: android

Currently, the splash screen is not displayed only when the application is closed.
I want to showing the splash screen when my app is return from background.

Comment: Splash screens are an anti-pattern: http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/ http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/07/trending-android-ui-anti-patterns.html http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEGWcMTxs3I http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhzAr9reu_4 https://plus.google.com/104844169030193199790 Please do not waste the user's time with a splash screen at all, let alone constantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the splash-screen displayed in onResume() method, as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414191/1027204

Answer (score -1):

In general splash screens are meant to display when an app is initially loaded with some background task to complete.So,splash screens are not always required when you return from apps menu.

Answer (score -2):

Call your `splash screen` activity on **onResume** method of each `activity` through `Intent`.

Comment: but on onResume can be called if i return from another Activity not from background

Comment: `onResume` is always called either coming back from Activity or from Background.

Comment: how can I differentiate between them