# Detecting android application going to background

Tags: android, activity-state

I need to turn off Bluetooth when my app "goes to background"/"becomes inactive".

I tried to do it in onPause() of my MainActivity but that doesn't work since now BT goes off (onPause() of the Mainactivity is fired) even when I start a new activity showing an entity detail of chosen item from the Mainactivity.

What I need is some kind of "onPause()" of my App not of a single activity.

I think nothing like this exists so is there any preferable solution?

Comment: Dude, I've faced this problem thousand times, but its our unfortunate that no such method or event exists.. You'll have to find a work around for it.

Comment: Put it in `onDestroy` and `onBackPressed` of the MainActivity so that when user closes the application bluetooth gets turned off.

Comment: onDestroy() isn't what I'm looking for since it can take time to this method get called

Answer (score 16):

> Pull this dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
}
```

> Then in your Application class, use this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements LifecycleObserver {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    private void onAppBackgrounded() {
        Log.d("MyApp", "App in background");
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    private void onAppForegrounded() {
        Log.d("MyApp", "App in foreground");
    }
}
```

> Update your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ....>
</application>
```

Comment: That's a great answer. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Worked like magic! By the way, is this an open source project? maybe on github? I would like to study how it works

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**: Beware, according to comments this does NOT work in all cases!!!

Solutions listed here on SO seem too complicated to me. I came up using this:

Create static variable accessible from all your Activities to detect count of currently running ones.

```
public class SharedData {
    static int runningActivities = 0;
}
```

In every activity override this two methods.

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (SharedData.runningActivities == 0) {
        // app enters foreground
    }
    SharedData.runningActivities++;
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedData.runningActivities--;
    if (SharedData.runningActivities == 0) {
        // app goes to background
    }
}
```

You can create MyActivity extending Activity, put this code in it and make all your Activities extend this class.

Comment: this does NOT work this is also triggered when activity is resumed by backbutton or when activity is entered from another activity

Comment: A pitfall of tracking activity count is rotation.  Often times, the activity that is going down finishes completely before the new activity for the new configuration comes up resulting in incorrect background->foreground transition detection.

Answer (score 3):

To detect that application is going to background, Override following method in Application class of your App :

```
@Override
public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
    super.onTrimMemory(level);
    if(level == ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN)
        //called when app goes to background
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refer this question [How to detect when an Android app goes to the background and come back to the foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414171/how-to-detect-when-an-android-app-goes-to-the-background-and-come-back-to-the-fo) the guy who answered this solved using `onFocuschanged` don't know how much effective is this method,anyway keep researching in google

```
private boolean isApplicationBroughtToBackground() {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
        if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: At least until now, it works with multiple activities for me.

Answer (score 2):

For a not single Activity app, I would recomend that every activity implements a time based control of visibility. Launch on every onPause() a timed status checker and also cancel this timer on every onResume() method.

Here an example

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    TimerTask backgroundCheck = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
                ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
                if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(getApplicationContext().getPackageName())) {
                    // APP in background, do something
                }
            }

            // APP in foreground, do something else
        }
    };

    Timer isBackgroundChecker = new Timer();
    isBackgroundChecker.schedule(backgroundCheck, 1000, 1000);

    super.onPause();
}
```

After implement that, remember to cancel the `Timer isBackgroundChecker = new Timer();`

Comment: do you have an example of this approach please?

Comment: getRunningTasks is deprecated in API level 21 (Lollipop). The document say that not use it, because it may be have a "break in the future"

Answer (score 2):

It is not advisable to use `RunningTaskInfo` because its  “method is only intended for debugging and presenting task management user interfaces“. well, if you are developing app for ICS and above I found this link very useful !

http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the onPause() on every activity you have, but I don't think it's needed to turn off bluetooth by yourself, some users may be using bluetooth for some other reason, or they want to turn it of themselves (that's what I do )

Comment: this won't work since it would mean BT would go off if I leave Main activity and open anaother Activity which is part of my app

Comment: you can maybe try working with fragments ? They can behave like activities and you can include them in a single activity, that turns of bluetooth when onPause() is called.