# How create Android widget available for all screen

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I want to develop an android application widget, `that will be available for all application screen not only for Home screen and Lock screen.`
Suppose User is using an application like navigation. At the same time he wants to control the music application through music widget.
I have created the widget and the widget is showing on the home screen.
But I want to show it on the all other application. I have searched a lot on the web, but every time I am getting the reference code for Home screen widget.I want to develop an widget application something like : 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keyboardr.widgetsanywhere

Answer (score 1):

The app you are referencing is not a desktop widget, but an actually application that uses a persistent overlay.

There are lots of examples of similar functionality, and you need to understand how to create a normal application that 'Floats' on top of other apps.

Not sure exactly how to do this, but I am sure that it is NOT a Widget, but an actual application.

Answer (score 1):

Look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21122798/2357411) where you can find out both:

- **how to create a floating application**
- **how to know what application is on foreground**, so you can decide if your application will show up (or any other logic you can have here, like for instance decide what content to show depending on what is the foreground application)