# load fragment when user reopens app android

Tags: android

Hi i'm trying to load a Fragment when a returns to the app. I'm trying to do this by setting a string in the system preferences that says session="not active" in my onPause() and session="active" in my onResume(); the problem is when i navigate to a new activity it also runs onPause() thus setting the session to not active. the result is that every time i go from one activity to another the my fragment loads. i should mention that the fragment contains a a pin input to keep the data secure thats why i need it. so to sum up does anyone know how to detect if when a user has returned to the app?

heres what i have tried so far

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);  // Add this method.
    saveStringToPreference(this, "user_session", "not_active");
    Log.v("Homepage", "onStop");
    Log.v("Homepage", "user_session= " + returnStringFromPreference(this, "user_session"));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    saveStringToPreference(this, "user_session", "not_active");
    Log.v("Homepage", "onDestroy");
    Log.v("Homepage", "user_session= " + returnStringFromPreference(this, "user_session"));
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    saveStringToPreference(this, "user_session", "active");
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
    Fragment pinFragment = new PinFragment();
    FragmentManager pinFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    pinFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, pinFragment).commit();

    Log.v("Homepage", "onResume");
    Log.v("Homepage", "user_session= " + returnStringFromPreference(this, "user_session"));
}



public void userPin(){
    if(userHasSetPin(this) == true){
        if(returnStringFromPreference(this, "user_session").equals("active")){
            fragment = new homePageFragment();
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        }else{
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.hide();
            Fragment pinFragment = new PinFragment();
            FragmentManager pinFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            pinFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, pinFragment).commit();


        }

    }else{
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        Fragment pinSetupFragment = new PinSetupFragment();
        FragmentManager pinSetupFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        pinSetupFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, pinSetupFragment).commit();

    }    

}
```

userPin() is then run in my onCreate();

Answer (score 1):

You just can't use onPause and onResume for this. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414171/how-to-detect-when-an-android-app-goes-to-the-background-and-come-back-to-the-fo) for solutions to how to do this.