# Detect when application is back from background

Tags: android, background, google-analytics

I would like to know when my app is back from background. onResume() is not a good solution, because i have another activities beside the Main Activity, so it can back from background to each of them. The purpose is to use `Google analytics` and to know when a user is launching the app and also bring it back from the background.

Thank you all and much appreciation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect when an Android app goes to the background and come back to the foreground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414171/how-to-detect-when-an-android-app-goes-to-the-background-and-come-back-to-the-fo)

Comment: [modern answer on another thread: Use ProcessLifecycleOwner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48767617/199364)

Answer (score 2):

Create a common base class which extends `Activity`.  Implement `onResume()` with the functionality you need.  Then extend all of your other activities from this base class.

The `onResume()` in the base class should call `super.onResume()` and this should also be the first line in each of the individual activity `onResume` methods.

**Base class**

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // code to do your analytics stuff
}
```

**Derived Activities**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // code for the individual activity
}
```

Comment: But would it will be called each time any of those activities call to onResume() (for example moving between activities)? in that case I will get false data for using the app.

Comment: Yes it will, but read the thread I linked in the "duplicate".

Comment: Doesn't help much, even with flags it causes problems but thanks anyway for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect background application with **ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()** which returns a list of RunningAppProcessInfo records. If your application is in the background check **RunningAppProcessInfo.importance** field equals to **RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND** while **RunningAppProcessInfo.processName** is equals to your **application package name**.

More info:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html

Answer (score 0):

The **android.arch.lifecycle** package provides an interface that let you know when the app is back from background.

Your application should implement the LifecycleObserver interface:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements LifecycleObserver {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    private void onAppBackgrounded() {
        Log.d("MyApp", "App in background");
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    private void onAppForegrounded() {
        Log.d("MyApp", "App in foreground");
    }
}
```

To do that, you need to add this dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
}
```

As recommended by Google, you should minimize the code executed in the lifecycle methods of activities:

> A common pattern is to implement the actions of the dependent
>   components in the lifecycle methods of activities and fragments.
>   However, this pattern leads to a poor organization of the code and to
>   the proliferation of errors. By using lifecycle-aware components, you
>   can move the code of dependent components out of the lifecycle methods
>   and into the components themselves.

You can read more here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle