# Background TimerTask gets killed when app is killed

Tags: java, android

I am using a passcode lock on my app. I set a varibale to true/false in shared preferences using the logic in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15573121/848471). But this approach doesn't work when I kill the app while still on foreground (using recent apps). Looks like killing the app kills my TimerTask which is scheduled for 2secs and hence the variable never gets set.

I have tried using services to do the same but no luck, even services get killed when the app is killed. Any workaround for this? Please help!!

Comment: What does the variable mean?

Comment: Variable here is essentially a boolean type value stored in Shared prefs.

Comment: I know, I'm asking what does it mean. I.e true means ... false means ...

Comment: Sorry for the obvious reply, true here means that the application(not a particular activity) is no longer in foreground, false means that application is still on foreground.

Comment: I see, well there is no need to store this off, you can test for in forground at anytime. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/checking-if-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-background/5862048#5862048

Comment: this will not work for me, as it will mark the activityVisible flag false in every activity transition. I only want it to be false if the app is no longer visible on foreground. Please refer to the link in question, I am using that approach now. But it has issues when I kill the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Service with START_STICKY, which will be recreated after killing. Check [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for events that will be launched by system even if your app is closed.

I personally suggest using the AlarmManager, instead of keeping long-running services.

Comment: Isn't AlarmManager same as TimerTask that I am using currently?

Comment: TimerTask is a Java object while AlarmManager is a system service where you can post PendingIntents for delayed execution. Both could work here but like you say your application gets killed, and so is your TimerTask, AlarmManager is a system service and will send intent to a killed app too. Just keep in mind that since KitKat all Alarms are inexact, see documentation for more details. [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: Thanks, this should solve my purpose. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: I tried using alarm manager, but result the same. It doesn;t work in the particular case I have mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to execute background tasks in an efficient way is to use an `IntentService`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

An `IntentService` is going to run in a separate thread as long as the task requires and will be killed afterwards.

Also it will enqueue requests and deal with the queue itself

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.