# buttons setpressed() in android resets when minimize the app and reopen it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have set button as setpressed() from code and and with help of style xml its colour changed but when minimize the app and reopen it then xml setpressed style resets and again its colour changed to default.
please help

Comment: go through the Activity life cycle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414171/how-to-detect-when-an-android-app-goes-to-the-background-and-come-back-to-the-fo

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your style & setpressed() (or else set some flag)in onResume() method because when app comes to front from background then onResume method is being called

Comment: cau you give me some demo regarding setting flag for button.

Comment: first show some code & where you are calling the setpressed() method

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.. there were many buttons and i have given id as b_1,b_2....
in below code I set them as setpressed(true) and after minimizing and resuming the same I set them back as setpressed(true) on the basis of setPaintFlags value.

android code:

```
String buttonID = "b_" + no ;
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", "com.sanjaypatil.housie");
        abc = ((Button) findViewById(resID));
        abc.setPressed(true);
        abc.setPaintFlags(1);

public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        String t;
        for(int l=1; l<=90; l++){
            t = "b_" + l;
            int resID2 = getResources().getIdentifier(t, "id", "com.abc.efg");
            abc2 = ((Button) findViewById(resID2));
            int flag = abc2.getPaintFlags();
            if(flag==1)
            {
                abc2.setPressed(true);
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: i am trying but stackoverflow doesn't allow me as i just joined and my reputation is lower than 15 :(