# start the service when app gets closed

Tags: android, service

I want to start a service when I press the home button or just press back (when the app is in the background but not killed)
how can I do a function that checks that ?
thanks to all

Comment: in onPause of your MainActivity, you start the service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when an Android app goes to the background and come back to the foreground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414171/how-to-detect-when-an-android-app-goes-to-the-background-and-come-back-to-the-fo)

Comment: You pretty much should not do that. this is my favorite answer on this question- http://stackoverflow.com/a/19920353/4810277

Comment: i just want to start a timer for when he quits it so i send him notification after some time now i have service when he kills the app but it doesnt work if its still in background

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Foreground` service using `startForeground()` method and `START_STICKY` flag. In breif, you have to say to the user 'my app is still working'.

Or the other implementation is to use `AlarmManager` if you want to charge the task for the future.

Comment: It doesn't work.
He want to check the application to background.

Comment: the other ways are not useful at all.

Comment: @ozmor , you can charge your service (or broadcast receiver) to be started at particular time . Or schedule periods.

Comment: then what ? can u write here plz the if stetment i can enter ?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) and attach it to your Application to now when your app is in background. Here is [Foreground example](http://steveliles.github.io/is_my_android_app_currently_foreground_or_background.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need a BaseActivity,and all other Activities must extend this BaseActivity:

as @Shoad said but the method that triggers is

```
    public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
     @Override
    protected void onPause() {

//Start Service or do what you want

    }
    }
```

Couldn't succed comment down

Answer (score -1):

You need a BaseActivity,and all Activities must extand this BaseActivity:

````
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        startService(new Intent(this, AService.class));
        //maybe you need check the AService is running here```
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
````

Comment: this code only check where user press backkey No more logic. not useful.