# Open the app automatically when you receive a push notification with onesignal

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

I would like to be able to open an activity in the application when a push notification is received without any user action.
Is it possible to do with onesignal or some other way to open the app automatically using a push?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this,hope this code will help you.

Intent restart = context.getPackageManager().
                    getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
            restart.addFlags(Intent.`enter code here`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            context.startActivity(restart);

Answer (score 0):

You can simply start your home activity inside `FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived` But if application is currently running you don't have to do that. You need kind of controller and check is application in [foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414171/how-to-detect-when-an-android-app-goes-to-the-background-and-come-back-to-the-fo)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I will check that, Really what I want to do would be the same as whatsapp for example when you receive a call, opens a screen to answer or refuse, is what I need to do, I'm on the right track or should Investigate something else?

Comment: @BraianOchoa If you need user action (answer or refuse) you have to start activity without care of application lifecycle.