# How to stop notification if app is in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a scenario when i don't want android system to display push notification if app is in foreground.

Instead i want to display some view or launch activity in the app.

This is my code.

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
  
       //...
       //...
      sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification(), subtitle);

}
```

If i comment out `sendNotification()`method, it does not display notification on both background & foreground cases.

Comment: Add Lifecycle support and check whether your activity is on Resumed or on Paused state and display notification if you're app is running in background (activity is onPause state)

Comment: @MD : Where to add Lifecycle support, in class that is extending from FirebaseMessagingService?

Comment: No at your app level class or base activity

Comment: Please checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965528/sending-a-push-notification-only-when-app-is-in-background

Answer (score 0):

> There are two types of messages data messages and notification
> messages. Data messages are handled here in onMessageReceived whether
> the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
> traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received
> here in onMessageReceived when the app is in the foreground. When the
> app is in the background an automatically generated notification is
> displayed. When the user taps on the notification they are returned to
> the app. Messages containing both notification and data payloads are
> treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends
> notification messages.

Thought you can only handle notification when app is in foreground.

Solution:-
**Tell your server that app is in foreground and background and they will send notification when app is in foreground only**