# Kill android application after X time

Tags: android, background, background-process, kill-process

I have been searching around for a way to kill my application after the user put it in the background for at least 30min.

So far what i have found things like :

```
getActivity().finish();
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
System.exit(1);

private void stopServices() {        
    final ActivityManager activityManager = SystemServices.getActivityManager(context);
    final List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> runningServices = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    final int pid = Process.myPid();
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo serviceInfo : runningServices) {
        if (serviceInfo.pid == pid && !SenderService.class.getName().equals(serviceInfo.service.getClassName())) {
            try {
                final Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(serviceInfo.service);
                context.stopService(intent);
            } catch (SecurityException e) { 
                 // handle exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty much what i have figered so far is taht after API 21 use

```
finishAndRemoveTask();
```

before that use `this.finishAffinity();`

But how to start timer once the app is put in the `background` for X time and then call the app kill method.

Answer (score 0):

So what I understand that you need 2 things:

1. Figure out when your app is in the background
2. Schedule a job.

So here are 2 links for this questions:

1. [How to detect if your app is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414171/how-to-detect-when-an-android-app-goes-to-the-background-and-come-back-to-the-fo)
2. [Schedule a job on Android](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling)

Comment: Ya thats what i have found out from search that i should use AppLifeCycleHandler and with it i can get when the app in background or foreground but now i have to start service once the app is in background and be able to cancel that specific service if the app switch to be in foreground