# How to get onTrimMemory callback with level int using androidx / support Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, androidx

Previously I was using android.app.Fragment which provided ComponentCallbacks2. I am now migrating my app to use androidx Fragment. However it says 'onTrimMemory overrides nothing'. I look and see that androidx Fragment only provides ComponentCallbacks. Is there any way to workaround and get the level int?

Comment: Do you need to use this for memory purposes or something different?

Comment: This is actually a great question. I have used onTrimMemory in the past to deal with [some hacky ways to determine when an app goes to the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414171/how-to-detect-when-an-android-app-goes-to-the-background-and-come-back-to-the-fo) but since that's no longer needed, I'm curious if you're expecting to do something when you receive this (not guaranteed) callback.

Comment: Using it for memory management purposes as it's intended. I would like the `level` to know just how important the notification is; since sometimes I do a couple different things depending on the severity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement `ComponentCallbacks2` in your `Fragment` and register it using `Context.registerComponentCallbacks`:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements ComponentCallbacks2 {

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        context.registerComponentCallbacks(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        requireContext().unregisterComponentCallbacks(this);
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTrimMemory(int level) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks promising; not sure how I missed that. Thanks