# Inconvertible types; cannot cast android.app.Application error?

Tags: android

**My goal is to detect when the user goes into the background.** I used [this answer to get me setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15573121/10565406)

However when I replace where there is *"MyApplication"* in his code, with my classname *("MainActivity")*. I can the inconvertible types error.

I'm new to android studio and do not know how to go about fixing this. Any and help is appreciated.

**Main Activity Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {



    private Timer mActivityTransitionTimer;
    private TimerTask mActivityTransitionTimerTask;
    public boolean wasInBackground;
    private final long MAX_ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_TIME_MS = 2000;

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        MainActivity myApp = (MainActivity)this.getApplication();
        if (myApp.wasInBackground)
        {
            //Do specific came-here-from-background code
        }

        myApp.stopActivityTransitionTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        ((MainActivity)this.getApplication()).startActivityTransitionTimer();
    }

   public void startActivityTransitionTimer() {
        this.mActivityTransitionTimer = new Timer();
        this.mActivityTransitionTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.this.wasInBackground = true;
            }
        };

        this.mActivityTransitionTimer.schedule(mActivityTransitionTimerTask,
                MAX_ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_TIME_MS);
    }

    public void stopActivityTransitionTimer() {
        if (this.mActivityTransitionTimerTask != null) {
            this.mActivityTransitionTimerTask.cancel();
        }

        if (this.mActivityTransitionTimer != null) {
            this.mActivityTransitionTimer.cancel();
        }

        this.wasInBackground = false;
    }
```

}

**Location of error**
[image]

**EDIT: AndroidManifest.xml below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jstudios.cars">


    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Cars"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="CarsApp"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Intent filter is for the splash screen.**

**EDIT: @Modi Harsh**

**LifeCycleObserverClassCode:**

[image]

**Directories Of LifeCycleObserver:**

[image]

**Input of Code in MainActivity:**

[image]

**EDIT 2 ERROR IN MainActivityJava:**

[image]

**EDIT 2 ERROR IN MyLifeCycleObserverClass:**

[image]

Comment: Just carefully study the link you posted. You have to implement your instance of application (don't forget to mention it in manifest). Your activity is not the same as your application, those two cannot be cast.

Comment: Yeah I saw some of the comments referencing what your saying. I don't understand what you mean by implementing my instance of application.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48767617/115145

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a class which extends Application - this is not the same as your Main activity. [The docs describe it as](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application):

> Base class for maintaining global application state. You can provide
>   your own implementation by creating a subclass and specifying the
>   fully-qualified name of this subclass as the "android:name" attribute
>   in your AndroidManifest.xml's  tag. The Application
>   class, or your subclass of the Application class, is instantiated
>   before any other class when the process for your application/package
>   is created.

It will look like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

}
```

Inside your Manifest.xml file you will need something like this to tell Android about your custom application class:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      package="your.package.name">

....

    <application
           android:name=".MyApplication"
           android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
           android:supportsRtl="true">
</manifest>
```

I think you need to move your `startActivityTransitionTimer` and `stopActivityTransitionTimer` methods to your new MyApplication class.

Then your `onPause` and `onResume` methods should be able to use this:

```
(MyApplication) this.getApplication()
```

PS you can call your `MyApplication` class anything you want.

PPS it might be worth reading about the [fundamentals of Android components here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification will definitely be reading those sources. I've followed your post instruction to the tee, but I still have same error. I think it's stemming from my application tab in the manifest. The error states "MyApplication is not assignable to android.app.application. I'm going to post my manifest files above maybe I'm overlooking something

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved through [Android Architecture Component: LifeCycle](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle)

Add in build.gradle

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
```

Create your Observer class and implements with `LifecycleObserver`

Kotlin :

```
class MyLifeCycleObserver : LifecycleObserver {

private var lifeCycleObserverCallback: LifeCycleObserverCallback? = null

    fun registerCallback(lifeCycleObserverCallback: LifeCycleObserverCallback) {
        this.lifeCycleObserverCallback = lifeCycleObserverCallback
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    private fun onAppForeground() {
        lifeCycleObserverCallback?.onForeground()
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    private fun onAppBackground() {
        lifeCycleObserverCallback?.onBackground()
    }

    public interface LifeCycleObserverCallback {
        fun onForeground()
        fun onBackground()
    }
}
```

Java :

```
public class MyLifeCycleObserver implements LifecycleObserver {

    private LifeCycleObserverCallback lifeCycleObserverCallback;

    public void registerCallback(LifeCycleObserverCallback lifeCycleObserverCallback) {
        this.lifeCycleObserverCallback = lifeCycleObserverCallback;
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    private void onAppForeground() {
        lifeCycleObserverCallback.onForeground();
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    private void onAppBackground() {
        lifeCycleObserverCallback.onBackground();
    }

    public interface LifeCycleObserverCallback{
        void onForeground();
        void onBackground();
    }
}
```

Add this few lines in your Activity in `onCreate`

Kotlin :

```
val observer = MyLifeCycleObserver()
lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
observer.registerCallback(this)
```

Java :

```
MyLifeCycleObserver observer = new MyLifeCycleObserver();
getLifecycle().addObserver(observer);
observer.registerCallback(this);
```

After that implements `LifeCycleObserverCallback` listener in your Activity and override both methods

Kotlin :

```
override fun onForeground() {
//    do whatever you want (App in Foreground)
}

override fun onBackground() {
//    do whatever you want (App in Background)
}
```

Java :

```
@Override
public void onForeground() {
//    do whatever you want (App in Foreground)
}

@Override
public void onBackground() {
//    do whatever you want (App in Background)
}
```

And done :)

Comment: Thanks for the help I'm implementing your solution. When you say create your observer class  Observer class and extends with LifecycleObserver, do I put that section of code in my mainactivity.java?

Comment: No, not in your activity. create a separate `Observer` class file in your app package.

Comment: ok so the only sections of code that I put in the main activity are the val observer = MyLifeCycleObserver() section as well as the override fun onForeground section in your answer?

Comment: Yes, exactly (y) and don't forget to implement those `LifeCycleObserverCallback` methods inside your activity. If it is helpful to you please upvote the answer :)

Comment: Ok thanks! looking forward to this, when I get on android studio, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok so I got some errors above I'm going to post where exactly I inputted your code

Comment: Code is written in `Kotlin` language so, you've to convert that code into `Java` or convert your code into `Kotlin`.

Comment: Ok so I re-added the java code. My mainactivtiy says cannot resolve lifecycle I'm posting images above. I think it has to do with my dependencies I'm using androidx

Comment: You can find all `AndroidX` libraries : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate