# Toast Message On Touch

Tags: android, android-toast

Is it possible to show toast message , when user touch on screen and close when user again touch screen .

Like I have many toast message to display based on user click on screen.

A sample code will be much more appreciated.

Comment: Use onTouchEvent()

Comment: take framelayout with width & height to `match_parent`. and put `onTouchListener()` on that.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer it's explained how you can show and cancel a toast when you desire: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13727852/6150890

To know when the user is touching the screen use an onTouchEvent(), you'll find plenty of examples if you google it