# Android - Custom Toast touch outside event

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

I'm trying to use a **Custom Toast** with `ImageView` and `TextView`.
I want my Toast to disappear when I touch anywhere (clicking button, touching layout...), but it doesn't.

I read the `Toast.class` file and tried using the `cancel()` method before a new Toast was called, but that didn't solve anything. Can anyone give me a solution?

My `CustomToast.java`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = new View(context);
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(
        R.id.layout_custom_toast));

layout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_custom_toast);
tvToast = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_custom_toast);
tvToast.setText(text);

ivToast = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_custom_toast);
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_style_red);
ivToast.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.warning);

Toast toast = new Toast(context);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setView(v);
toast.show();
```

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/10070108/1979347

Comment: Please check this 
http://blog.ravinishad.com/post/84906000396/toasts-dont-annoy-me

Comment: Solution is to build a `Toast` based on an (dismissable) `AlertDialog`. Lots of tutorials and questions about it.

Comment: Thanks for responses. @shkschneider - I solved this problem by initializing toast object with Toast.makeText(...), removing all views and  adding ImageView and TextView.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Post your solution as an answer, then accept it yourself to close this question please.

Answer (score 0):

Solution : I used `Toast.makeText(...)` instead of `new Toast(..)` because it inflates resource in hidden api(com.android.internal.R) and you cannot access to it. Initializing toast object with `Toast.makeText(...)` makes you access to hidden api simply.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);

layout = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
layout.removeAllViews();
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

int dftPadding = (int) StaticValues.dpToPixel(context, 10);
layout.setPadding(dftPadding, dftPadding, dftPadding, dftPadding);
ivToast = new ImageView(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(0, 0, (int) StaticValues.dpToPixel(context, 5), 0);
ivToast.setLayoutParams(params);
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_style_red);
ivToast.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.warning);
layout.addView(ivToast);
tvToast = new TextView(context);
tvToast.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tvToast.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
tvToast.setText(text);
layout.addView(tvToast);
toast.show();
```