# how to know the number of toast in the tail

Tags: android, message, toast

I like to know how to get a list of messages that will be displayed as Toast. When there are several problems that break some of the duration of the display. thank's !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Because Toast que is owned by android-VM. You can push in new toasts or cancel an existing toast (if you have its reference object), but cannot count total or cancel all. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2755436/966550) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#cancel%28%29)