# Stop a Toast and start another in android

Tags: android, toast

I am using Toast in my app. When I am pressing a button, it is showing a Toast. My problem is that the second time I'm pressing on the button the second toast is "waiting" for the first one to end and only than it shows..  I want the current one to show immediately and not wait.
This is my simple code:

```
toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press Back to retorn to the main page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

how can I do that?

Comment: not even a wierd workaround?!

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov no it is not.

Comment: Did you try to use setDuration of the visible Toast before the call show() on the new one?
I don't know if it's works but it's the only possible workaround I see.

Comment: only two option... long or short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/4485531/517561, the writer didn't cancel the toast, they simply changed its text.

Answer (score 6):

You can always [cancel a Toast object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#cancel%28%29).

```
final Toast tst = Toast.makeText(ctx, "This is a toast.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
tst.show();

Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           tst.cancel(); 
           tst.setText("Same toast with another message.");
           tst.show();
       }
}, 1000);
```

So instead of creating another Toast object you can use the first one, cancel it, set the new text and show it again.

Comment: cancelling won't reduce the toast time.

Comment: its not doing the job...

Comment: It does. You need to call the cancel on the toast object itself.

Comment: but you cant have another one showing after that.

Comment: initialise the object every time u want to show the toast.

Comment: see my updated answer. it simply works for me.

Comment: Removed the -1,because finally you understood what the OP asked for.

Comment: its not, its simply removing the first toast but the second one still waints the ""Toast.length_short"...

Comment: I updated my answer to demonstrate how you can cancel a toast before it would disappear by itself and show the same! toast with modified text.

Answer (score 2):

Cancel your original `Toast`, set a new message and show again the `Toast` message.

```
Toast mytoast;
mytoast = Toast.makeText(this, "Hi Ho Jorgesys! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
mytoast.show();
....
....
....
if(CancelToast){
  mytoast.cancel();  //cancelling old Toast!
  mytoast = Toast.makeText(this, "Same toast with another message.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); //Setting a new message.
  mytoast.show(); //Show the new message!.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use toast.cancel() befor showing next toast.

Comment: cancelling won't reduce the toast time.

Comment: Thanks  Kazekagebut, but as per defination Close the view if it's showing, or don't show it if it isn't showing yet. You do not normally have to call this. Normally view will disappear on its own after the appropriate duration.

Comment: public void cancel ()
Since: API Level 1

Close the view if it's showing, or don't show it if it isn't showing yet. You do not normally have to call this. Normally view will disappear on its own after the appropriate duration.

Comment: The other toast will come after the fixed amount of time that it is supposed to wait,whether you cancel the first toast or not!

Comment: Cancelling the `Toast` works perfectly, and absolutely reduces the toast time if done correctly. Check sample code in [this related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098151/android-cancel-toast-when-exiting-the-app-and-when-toast-is-being-shown), or link to github and just copy the gist. Code has been production tested for a few years so far.