# Can i permanently disable toast message service in android & ios from react native or main activity?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-studio

We have a React Native app that using third party libraries, and they generate some toasts.
Now, finding a way to disable my app toast messaging service. Then, we could be handled toast messaging custom way.

> Is it possible to disable **React Native** toast messaging
> **permanently**?

Or,

> Is it possible to disable toast messaging **permanently** from
> **Android Studio**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, without having the reference of Toast, it is not possible.

> You can cancel individual Toasts by calling cancel() on the Toast object. AFAIK, there is no way for you to cancel all outstanding Toasts, though.

[Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2755436/2930834)

Even the React native does not have any respective methods to cancel the toast.

[Ref 2](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/77ecc7ede1da8fc590d7bc238a2fc02daa736746/Libraries/Components/ToastAndroid/ToastAndroid.android.js)